# Query to return data

Tags: mysql

I have an database that has 7 tables and each tables has one columns that i want get it under one condition.

[image]

Here i have my database with all the columns(alarme, ar_condicionado, audio, estore, iluminacao, porta and tv).
And I want get these column: descricao of all tables, if the column divisao is the same in each one table.
[image]

Comment: you'll need to JOIN them; did you try any code that may have failed you?

Comment: Not sure what what format you want this in. An inner join on all 7 tables on divisao and then select descricao might get what you are after.

Comment: [.....I guess not then.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475139/query-to-return-data#comment70156420_41475139)

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I tried a lot of functions like join union select show but nothing worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

```
select tab1.descricao,tab2.descricao,tab3.descricao,tab4.descricao,tab5.descricao,tab6.descricao,tab7.descricao from tab1
inner join tab2 on tab1.divisao = tab2.divisao 
inner join tab3 on tab1.divisao = tab3.divisao 
inner join tab4 on tab1.divisao = tab4.divisao 
inner join tab5 on tab1.divisao = tab5.divisao 
inner join tab6 on tab1.divisao = tab6.divisao 
inner join tab7 on tab1.divisao = tab7.divisao
```

Comment: He wants `descricao` from each table that he joins with.

Comment: But for example if i dont have descricao in one of the tables i can get nothing from this.